# update variable from multiple tables in one row

Tags: mysql, set, sql-update, mariadb

I have two databases, and I need to UPDATE variable 'birthday' from one row to another checking 'name' (from db1 to db2).

The problem is, that 'name' variable in second db is located in another table (table2).
It is possible to do this without changing DB structure using 'id' variable from db2 to synchronizing?

```
UPDATE `db1`.`table1`, `db2`.`table2` SET `db2`.`table1`.`birthday` = `db1`.`table1`.`birthday` WHERE `db2`.`table1`.`name` ...
```

Scheme:

```
 db1-> table1 -> name,birthday
 db2-> table1 -> name,id     
       table2 -> birthday,id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `db.1`.table1 AS t11
JOIN `db.2`.table1 AS t21 ON t11.name = t21.name
JOIN `db.2`.table2 AS t22 ON t21.id = t22.id
SET t11.birthday = t22.birthday
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's worked perfectly. But I can't to this when I try to update between 2 databases (from one server). Even when I've specify full path (`dbname`.`table`.`row`) I have ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected.

Comment: I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653577/mysql-error-1046-3d000-no-database-selected-on-update-query . If it's really a bug, that's bad.

Comment: My fault, I have a dot in DB name and somehow when I want UPDATE `db.2`.`table2` I've got ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db.2.table2' doesn't exist. But in SELECT and others all works fine.

Comment: If you have a dot (or other special character) in the DB name, you have to put backticks around it.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would work differently in `UPDATE` and `SELECT`.

Comment: The bug in the other question only occurs when you don't have a default database selected. Is that the case here?

Comment: Correct. I can't select default db because I've made queries to several databases.

Comment: You can still have a default database. When you specify a database prefix, it overrides the default.